# How do you read a file and set specific float values to a specific array in java?

Tags: java, filereader

Say I had a file set up like this:

20      88.6

16      71.6

19.8    93.3

18.4    84.3

17.1    80.6

15.5    75.2

14.7    69.7

17.1    82

The two float values are separated by a space, say that the ones on the left are x values and the ones on the right are y values how would I read the file and store the x values in one array and the y values in another?

```
public static Float[] getData() throws FileNotFoundException {
    float data;
    List<Float> temps = new ArrayList<Float>();

    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("cricket"));
    while(inFile.hasNext()) {

        data = inFile.nextFloat();
        temps.add(data);

    }
    inFile.close();

    for(int i = 0; i<=temps.size(); i++) {
    Float[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new Float[0]);

    }
    return tempsArray;


}
```

This is my code so far, I have all of the values in a single array, I'm not sure how to split them up.

Comment: Have you attempted this, if so, post your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You can encapsulate the content of each line as an object of type `Data` and add them to an `ArrayList`. Then, you can read each element of the `ArrayList` of `Data` and add it to two arrays: `arrX` and `arrY`, which you can use. See the example below.

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {    
      List<Data> dataList = getData("cricket");
      final int size = dataList.size();
      float[] arrX = new float[size];
      float[] arrY = new float[size];
      int i = 0;
      for (Data data : dataList) {
         arrX[i] = data.x;
         arrY[i] = data.y;
         i++;
      }
      // now you can use the arrX and arrY arrays
   }

   public static List<Data> getData(String file) throws FileNotFoundException {
      List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
      try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(file))) {
         while (sc.hasNext()) {
            dataList.add(new Data(sc.nextFloat(), sc.nextFloat()));
         }
      }
      return dataList;
   }

   static class Data {
      float x;
      float y;

      public Data(final float x, final float y) {
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about setting up the file with a delimiter character? Then you can do a split() and add each side of the split to the corresponding array.